# *ngFor not updating after server response is bound

Tags: angular, typescript

After working with Knockout for 5 years I've decided to play around with the latest version of Angular for a change of pace; so I'm relatively new to Angular.

**Issue**

On click a call is made to the server, does some stuff and sends back a response. Everything server side goes off without issue issue and from debugging I can see the object is bound correctly. However, the UI is acting like a stubborn mule and won't update even with configuration to affect the change tracking.

**Code**

Typescript/Angular Markup

```
import { Component, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

// Models
import { ContactRequest } from "../../Models/Contact/ContactDetailsRequest";
import { ContactDetailsResponse } from "../../Models/Contact/ContactDetailsResponse";

// Payloads
import { ContactBreakdownPayload } from "../../Payload/Contact/ContactPostPayload";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./contact.component.html"
})

export class ContactComponent {
  private BaseUrl: string;
  private HttpClientObject: HttpClient;

  public ChangeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef;
  public Contacts: Array<ContactDetailsResponse> = [];

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.BaseUrl = baseUrl;
    this.HttpClientObject = httpClient;
    this.ChangeDetection = changeDetection;
  }

  public RetrieveContactDetails(): void {
    const payload = {
      ContactBreakdowns: ContactBreakdownPayload
    } as ContactRequest;

    this.HttpClientObject.post(`${this.BaseUrl}contact`, payload)
      .subscribe((response: Array<ContactDetailsResponse>) => {
        console.log(response);

        this.Contacts = response;

        console.log(this.Contacts);

        this.ChangeDetection.detectChanges();
      });
  }
}
```

HTML Markup

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block"
        (click)="RetrieveContactDetails()">
  Retrieve contacts
</button>

<table class="table table-striped"
       style="margin-top: 0.625rem">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">First name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last name</th>
      <th scope="col">Date of birth</th>
      <th scope="col">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let Contact of ContactDetails">
      <td>TEST</td>
      <td>TEST</td>
      <td>TEST</td>
      <td>TEST</td>
      <td>TEST</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Question**

Based on the above can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this as it's probably just some basic implementation I've missed.

Comment: I don't see the `ContactDetails` from the template in the controller.

Comment: Oh my.... You know when you do something so stupid and paste it to the world... Thanks for spotting that, appreciated.

Comment: Much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving your server response in **Contacts** variable so you have to change *ngFor="let Contact of ContactDetails" to  *ngFor="let Contact of Contacts"

Comment: Thanks for the input, pretty much the same answer as Michael D. Either way I'll mark this as correct due to my 'stupidity'